# Groovy - add new nested key to map

Tags: groovy

I have 2 json files:

```
 Json A:
 {
  "a": {
    "b": true,
    "c": {
      "d": "Hello"
    }
  }
}

Json B:
    {
      "a": {
        "c": {
          "e": "Sir"
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm converting both json objects to MAP:

```
MAP A: [a:[b:true, c: [d: hello]]
MAP B: [a:[c: [e: Sir]]
```

I need to add element e to from json B to the same place in Json A

The expected result is:

```
Merged MAP : [a:[b:true, c: [d: hello, e: Sir]]
```

I have the the key that needs to be added as a doted path string (a.c.e)

How can I add a dot string path to an existing map?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what exactly do you need? Are you talking about adding an object to the map or about source json file manipulation? What is the expected result (a map, a file and of which structure). Also please show what have you done to read from the json and how exactly do you want to update the map (even though its a wrong code) - it will help to understand your intentions. I feel that you're trying to solve a real issue here but the question is hard to understand and provide a valuable feedback...

Comment: @MarkBramnik Thanks. I edited my question and added some examples, I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming you know what to add and the path 'a.c.e' as a string:
Something like this should do the job:

```
mapA = [a:[b:true, c: [d: 'hello']]]
mapB = [a:[c: [d: 'Sir']]]
path = 'a.c.e'
///////////////////////

allElems = (path.split("\\.") as List)
allButLast = allElems[0..-2] // [a, c]
last  = allElems[-1]         // e

mapToAddElemTo =
    allButLast        .stream()
                      .reduce(mapA, { currMap, pathElem -> currMap[pathElem] } )

mapToAddElemTo[last] = 'Sir'
println(mapA) // prints [a:[b:true, c:[d:hello, e:Sir]]]
```

Comment: Thanks ! currMap is mapB?

Comment: No, its a variable that points on the current inner map during unfolding...